# Elasticsearch and Spring Compatibility (March 2019)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am going to start a Spring Data Elasticsearch project but looking on the net, I haven't managed to understand what versions I should use.

I want to use Elasticsearch 5.5.
What versions of Spring Boot and Spring Data Elasticsearch should I use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this Spring github page https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Spring-Data-Elasticsearch---Spring-Boot---version-matrix, you can find compatible versions of Spring Boot, Spring Data ElasticSearch and ElasticSearch.

Currently supported versions of ElasticSearch are **< 5.0.0**

Edit: This page I posted is probably outdated. I'm sorry for confusing.
On git project of spring-data-elasticsearch is in README that for using Elasticsearch 5.5.0 you can use Spring data elasticsearch 3.0.x https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch

Comment: I had seen this matrix but I assumed that there would be an update! anyway, thanks for the answer, I will try to use Elasticsearch 2.4.

Comment: Updated answer to the question

Comment: thanks for the update! I have already started with 2.4.4, so I can’t confirm if that works! if anyone uses these versions he can confirm the answer!